# Python CPLEX API: Conditional iteration on binary variables

Tags: python, iteration, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I'm working on a graph-theoretical problem. Suppose we want to find a Graph G=(V,E), such that there exists a partition X of V containing at most k equivalence classes. A variable p_S takes value 1 exactly when S is a member of partition X, and zero otherwise. So we have a constraint that the sum over all variables p_S is at most k, for all subsets S of V.

So what I want to do is to iterate over all p_S that have value 1 and define more constraints based on the elements I draw out of S. These constraints would preserve that members of an equivalence class share some mutual property.

Is it possible to access the p_S variables that way and how could I do it?

ALternatively I know I can do without iterating on my binary variables if I'm allowed to use binary variables as coefficients in my constraints. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, you will need to linearize it. And yes, `if I'm allowed to use binary variables as coefficients in my constraints` is the basic concept behind this, but you can't *multiply* two variables in general, meaning, that you need to linearize those products (binary * binary, binary * int, binary * cont) (by additional variables and constraints). For each of those linearizations, there are different approaches and *assumptions* which are needed (e.g. a-priori bounds)! As this is very model-dependent (which we don't know), there isn't much more to say.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand the concept of linearisation, could you provide an example for the case binary* binary? It doesn't have to relate to my model.

Comment: [B/B](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/38/231), [B/C](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2010/10/binary-variables-and-quadratic-terms.html)

Comment: @sascha These are great examples, thanks! If you make a formal answer out of your replys I will accept it.

Comment: So linearizing a product of binary variables involves formulating constraints which contain a decision variable in the righthand-side. I just realized that in the Python CPLEX API the righthand side must be a real number. So how do I make this work?

Comment: It looks you are working with the low-level interface. See the posted answer by Alex Fleischer for some high-level code. If you stick to low-level coding / matrix-form, it's just basic math: `z<=x <-> z-x <= 0 <-> 1 * z - 1 * x <= 0`. (Without some experience including algebraic-coding i would not recommend a low-level interface)

Comment: This idea should have taken a second to come, but it somehow just didn't. Thanks for pointing it out anyway. And you are right, I'm stuck in low-level coding, because I have to modify an existing project. So anyway, I should be fine now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CPLEX Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html) is index based. To iterate over all binary variables with a solution value set to 1 we need to query the variables types and the solution values and filter accordingly. Here is a simple example:

```
import sys
import cplex


def main(modelfile):
    # Read in a model file.
    c = cplex.Cplex()
    c.read(modelfile)

    # Solve the model and print the solution and status.
    c.solve()
    print("Solution value:", c.solution.get_objective_value())
    print("Solution status: {0} ({1})".format(
        c.solution.get_status_string(),
        c.solution.get_status()))

    # Display all binary variables that have a solution value of 1.
    types = c.variables.get_types()
    nvars = c.variables.get_num()
    binvars = [idx for idx, typ
               in zip(range(nvars), c.variables.get_types())
               if typ == c.variables.type.binary]
    inttol = c.parameters.mip.tolerances.integrality.get()
    binvars_at_one = [idx for idx, val
                      in zip(binvars, c.solution.get_values(binvars))
                      if abs(val - 1.0) <= inttol]
    print("Binary variables with a solution value equal to one:")
    for varname in c.variables.get_names(binvars_at_one):
        print("  ", varname)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        raise ValueError("usage: {0} <model>".format(sys.argv[0]))
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

For more, see the documentation for [Cplex.variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.VariablesInterface-class.html) and [Cplex.solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.SolutionInterface-class.html).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your answer made me realize that the way I phrased the question made no sense in the first place, because it would requiere to have the solution values before solving the optimization problem to conditionally define more constraints based on them. So I will stick to linearization as sascha pointed out.

Comment: No problem. However, it is not uncommon for one to solve an original model, add more constraints, and solve again in a loop until some desired state is reached. By default, CPLEX will retain the solution information from the previous solve and use it as starting information for subsequent solves. I assumed you were thinking of doing something like that.

Comment: That's interesting! I didn't know about that. I guess then this is actually the right answer for the question I formulated, so I will accept this.

Answer (score 0):

linearization example:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='binaryproduct')

x = mdl.binary_var(name='x')
y = mdl.binary_var(name='y')

z = mdl.binary_var(name='z')
# z==x*y
mdl.add_constraint(x+y<=1+z, 'ct1')
mdl.add_constraint(z<=x, 'ct2')
mdl.add_constraint(z<=y, 'ct3')
#end of z==x*y

mdl.solve()



for v in mdl.iter_binary_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```